# Asp.Net hide url of file

Tags: asp.net

I hav an Asp.NET site that displays a PDF/Word/Excel file but I would like to hide the location of the file i.e. if the user requests a file via a link instead of displaying the path just open the filename, I've seen some other posts on other sites but since they are old they do not wok.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this is to write a custom .ashx handler, which implements IHttpHandler.

Implement the ProcessRequest(..) method, and pipe the file out in the response (here's an example from an application I wrote a while back:

```
 Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim inline As Boolean = Boolean.Parse(context.Request.QueryString("Inline"))
        Dim fileName As String = context.Request.QueryString("fileName")
        If (fileName.Contains("\")) Then Throw New Exception(String.Format("Invalid filename {0}.  Looks like a path was attempted", fileName))


        Dim filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FileDirectory") + "\" + fileName
        With context.Response
            .Buffer = True
            .Clear()

            If inline Then
                .AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; ; filename=" & IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath))
            Else
                .AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; ; filename=" & IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath))
            End If

            .WriteFile(filePath)

            If fileName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".PDF") Then
                .ContentType = "application/pdf"
            ElseIf fileName.EndsWith(".htm") Or fileName.EndsWith(".html") Then
                .ContentType = "text/html"
            ElseIf fileName.EndsWith(".tif") Then
                .ContentType = "image/tiff"
            ElseIf fileName.EndsWith(".jpeg") Or fileName.EndsWith(".jpg") Then
                .ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            End If

            .End()
        End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ASP.NET ASHX Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)

Some ASP.NET files are dynamically generated. They are generated with C# code or disk resources. These files do not require web forms. Instead, an ASHX generic handler is ideal. It can dynamically return an image from a query string, write XML, or any other data.